# Logging to host from Docker container does not work

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a Microservices based application and the services work fine if I deploy them on a host machine. But now, I'd like to learn Docker, so I started to use containers on a linux based machine. Here is a sample Docker file, it is really simple:

```
  FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim
  MAINTAINER BeszterceKK
  COPY ./tao-elszamolas-config.jar /usr/src/taoelszamolas/tao-elszamolas-config.jar
  WORKDIR /usr/src/taoelszamolas
  ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE prod
  EXPOSE 9001
  ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "tao-elszamolas-config.jar", "-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:/tao-elszamolas/services/tao-config/log4j2-    prod.xml", "-DlogFileLocation=/tao-elszamolas/logs"]
```

My problem is that, I try to write my Spring boot application log to the host machine. This is why I use data volumes. At the end this is the command how I run the container:

```
docker run -d --name=tao-elszamolas-config-server --publish=9001:9001 -v /tao-elszamolas/logs:/tao-elszamolas/logs -v /tao-elszamolas/services/tao-config/log4j2-prod.xml:/tao-elszamolas/services/tao-config/log4j2-prod.xml tao-elszamolas-config:latest
```

But on a longer term all of the services will go under "docker-compose". This is just for the test, something like a proof of concept.

First question is, why it is not writing the log to the right place. (In one of the volumes defined.) That is what I set in the Log4j2 config xml. If I use the config XML on local without Docker everything works fine. When I log into the container, then I can see the mounted volumes and I can "cd" into it. And I also can do this:

```
touch something.txt
```

So the file will be created and can be seen both from container and host machine. What am I doing wrong? I think, the application can pick up the log config, because when I just set an internal folder as the location of the log file, it logs the stuff inside the container.

And I also set the permissions of the whole volume (and its children) to 777 temporarily to test out if the permissions were the problem. But not. Any help would be very much appreciated!

My second question, is there any good web based tool on linux where I can manage my containers. Start them, stop then, etc... I googled it out and found some but not sure which one is the best and free for basic needs, and which one is enough secure.

Comment: Your second question is off-topic (Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Managed to resolve this problem after spending couple of nights with this.

I had multiple problems. First of all, the order of the system properties in the Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT section wasn't quite right. The

```
-Dsomething=something
```

must be before the "-jar". Otherwise it is not working in Docker. I haven't found any official documentation stating that, but this is how it is working for me. So the right ENDPOINT definition looks like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-DlogFileLocation=/tao-elszamolas/logs", "-jar", "tao-elszamolas-config.jar"]
```

Secondly, when I mounted some folders up to the container with docker run command like this:

```
-v /tao-elszamolas/logs:/tao-elszamolas/logs
```

then the log file wasn't written, if the folder in the Docker container doesn't exist by default. But if I create that folder at some point before the ENTRYPOINT in the Dockerfile, then the logging is fine, the system writes its logs to the host machine. I also didn't find any documentation stating these facts, but this is my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide some steps for verification:

Both Log4j and spring boot in general, should not be aware of any docker-related things, like volumes, mapped folders and so forth.

Instead, configure the logging of the application as if it works without docker at all, so if you want a local file - make sure that the application indeed produces the logging file in a folder of your choice.

The next step would be mapping the folder with volumes in docker / docker-compose.
But first please validate the first step:

```
docker ps // to see the container id
docker exec -it <CONTAINER_ID> bash
// now check the logging file from within the docker container itself even without volumes
```

If the logging file does not exist its a java issue and you should configure logging properly. If not - it's a docker issue.

Comment: Everything works fine without Docker. It also works fine if I set up the logging to produce the log file into a folder inside the container. But when this folder is on a volume mounted from host, then no log file created. The application reads the log4j config from the mounted volume, so it looks like my application can read from there. But it can’t write to mounted volumes.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in your entrypoint after log4j2- and before prod.xml:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "tao-elszamolas-config.jar", "-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:/tao-elszamolas/services/tao-config/log4j2-    prod.xml", "-DlogFileLocation=/tao-elszamolas/logs"]
```

It might be a problem.

Comment: No. It is just how the copy-paste works.  There is no space on that point. Unfortunately. I'd be really happy if this was the issue.